# Do something when publish a post in Gutenberg with hook rest_after_insert_post

Tags: rest-api, block-editor

I want to send my post to Telegram when it is created.  I have [read discussion here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327221/how-do-i-access-post-meta-data-when-publishing-a-new-post-in-gutenberg) and [inspected these code from n7studio](https://gist.github.com/n7studios/56fd05f19f5da26f19f6da0ccb57b144), but my function `send_posts_to_Telegram` doesn't fire when I publish `post`.  Isn't `rest_after_insert_post` fire when post are being published from REST API and Gutenberg?

```
add_action('rest_after_insert_post', 'send_posts_to_Telegram', 10, 3);

function send_posts_to_Telegram($post, $request, $creating = true){
//Send post to Telegram
}
```

Comment: "my code doesn't work" - how does it not work? Your function isn't getting called? And are you referring to the default `post` post type? If not, then you should use `rest_after_insert_<post type>`.

Comment: The function wasn't called, and yes I am referring to the default ```post``` type.  Any idea why?

Btw I will edit my question to make it more specific.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you very sure the function isn't getting called? Have you tried something simple like `function send_posts_to_Telegram() { error_log( 'send_posts_to_Telegram called' ); }` and check the PHP's `error_log`/logs file? And where did you put your code? In the theme `functions.php` file? In a plugin? But your code seems fine and yes, WordPress fires the `rest_after_insert_post` hook when a post is edited/created via the block editor.

Comment: So you are right!  The problem was in my own function but not with the ```rest_after_insert_post```.  It did fire as it should.  Didn't realize there is something call ```error_log()``` and now I see how useful it is.  Thanks!